# What is the proper way to clone an object 1000x with python?

Tags: python, scripting, loop

I am building a Minecraft-like map inside Blender, say a mountain or a plain. I want to repeatedly clone a cube with grass or stone texture that I already prepared, and place it at the correct spot.

Problem: the cloning loop gets exponentially slower. It needs 2s to create 300 cubes, 6s for 600, and 14s for 900.
What would be the right way to do it ? Is there a way with a more linear time-complexity ?

---

Here is what I've tried so far: I already identified the `original_cube` that I will then duplicate, and one of the two versions of `create_clone` is called in a loop.

```
def create_clone(x, y, z):

    # Select the cube
    unselect_everything()
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = original_cube
    bpy.data.objects[original_cube.name].select_set(True)

    # Duplicate the cube
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=True)
    clone = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active

    # Place the duplicate where it should be
    clone.location = (x, y, z)
```

Second version:

```
def create_clone_2(x, y, z):

    # Initial object
    src_obj = bpy.context.active_object
    
    new_obj = src_obj.copy()
    new_obj.data = src_obj.data.copy()
    new_obj.animation_data_clear()
    new_obj.location = (x, y, z)
```

Comment: You are cloning data, it is not effective. Instead, consider cloning data using instances, for example using vertex instancing

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution: I simply used an Array modifier !

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='ARRAY')
```

It creates a thousand objects in less than a second.

Comment: No it doesn't, it creates one single large objects with lots of identical parts